# integrating emotion/css with nextjs app router

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, emotion, app-router, css-in-js

I have been using emotion/css for my project and want to migrate to nextjs app router but have some questions regarding emotion/css server side rendering with app router.

Nextjs documentation states that emotion is working on support for app router [link](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/styling/css-in-js)

Material-ui is built with emotion (but uses emotion/styled) an works with nextjs app router [link](https://mui.com/material-ui/integrations/nextjs/#app-router)

also there are some workarounds all over the internet to make emotions work with app router, but all of them are for emotion/styled. (the solutions are working)

Can someone, please, explain why is it only emotion/stylied. Am i missing something fundamental here? because i don' t think that they are that different. I have been trying to find answers for few days now :D  Should i just give up and switch to emotion/styled?